# Activate Ribbon Button from C# in PowerPoint

Tags: c#, powerpoint, ribbon-control

How might it be possible to activate one of PowerPoint's ribbon buttons from C# ?

We want to be able to run some code in the context that is set up by pressing one of the ribbon buttons.

Just running our code via the interop doesn't work.

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
Ribbon.GetControlByName(controlName).DoClick()
```

Does anyone know if something like this might be possible, or know that it's not possible ?

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro? Then you will see what commands are executed by Word when that button is clicked.

Comment: Nice Idea. this needs to happen from PowerPoint, but one can no longer record macro's from PowerPoint these days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going old school on you, but [this](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00946.htm) is one of the best ways (still) to do this, assuming there is a Ribbon<->CommandBar coorelation.

Comment: Yes ! something like this does work. The answer lies with the routine CommandBars.ExecuteMso(idMso), http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa434602.aspx